# class instantiation in nested classes

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

I have the following problem:

```
template< typename T, size_t N, size_t... N_i >
struct A
{
  // nested class
  template< typename... Ts >
  class B
  {
      //...

      A<T, N_i...>::B< Ts... > operator[]( size_t i )
      {
        A< T, N_i...>::B< Ts... > res{ /* ... */ };

        return res;
      }

      // ...
  };
};
```

Unfortunately, the compiler yields an error for "`A < T, N_i...>::B < Ts... > res{ /* ... */ };`". Does anyone know how I can return an instantiation of the `class B` (which differs in its template arguments of his outer `class A`) in the function "`operator[]`" of `class B`?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be enough add a `typename` before `A<T, N_i...>` and a `template` before `B< Ts... >`.

I mean

```
template< typename T, size_t N, size_t... N_i >
struct A
{
  // nested class
  template< typename... Ts >
  class B
  {
      //...

      typename A<T, N_i...>::template B< Ts... > operator[]( size_t i )
      {
        typename A< T, N_i...>::template B< Ts... > res{ /* ... */ };

        return res;
      }

      // ...
  };
}
```

P.s.: should work also with C++11; not only with C++14

Answer (score 2):

Putting a `typename` before the full type of the return types is what fixes the errors you're getting.   However, don't put the template parameters after the B as B always refers to the "current" instantiation of the type.

```
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

template< typename T, size_t N, size_t... N_i >
struct A
{
  // nested class
  template< typename... Ts >
  class B
  {
      //...

      typename A<T, N_i...>::B operator[]( size_t i )
      {
        typename A< T, N_i...>::B res{ /* ... */ };

        return res;
      }

      // ...
  };
};
```

https://godbolt.org/g/hsB4pW

Comment: sorry but I'm not sure to understand; the `operator[]` in your answer return what? An `A<T, N, N_i ...>::B<Ts...>` or an `A<T, N_i...>::B<Ts...>`? If I understand correctly, the OP ask for an `A<T, N_i...>::B<Ts...>`

Comment: sorry again: with "Putting a `namespace` before the full type" do you mean "Putting a `typename` before the full type"?